# How to print a variable inside a loop in R installed in ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu

A similar question has been asked here about 3 years ago [How do I print a variable inside a for loop to the console in real time, as the loop is running, in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674975/how-do-i-print-a-variable-inside-a-for-loop-to-the-console-in-real-time-as-the) . Similar to that problem when I run for loop its showing every output variable to screen without clearing the previous one.

```
a=matrix(c(1,8,2,5),nrow=2)
for(i in 1:4){
  print(a*i)
}
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    8    5
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]   16   10
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    6
[2,]   24   15
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    8
[2,]   32   20
```

For simplicity I am using only four iterations for a low dimension matrix but my real for loop has more than 1000 iterations and a big dimension matrix which makes the output ugly and memory intensive.

I tried out the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15675061/996366) in the above asked question

```
for(i in 1:10){
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  print(i)
  flush.console() 
}
```

but it didnt changed anything in my R output (installed in ubuntu) and it still prints out all the variable

NOTE: I am not looking for a progress bar

Comment: You should probably save them, not print them. Also, you should probably be using `lapply`, not `for`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `system('clear')`, as suggested in an answer to [Function to clear the console in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260340/function-to-clear-the-console-in-r). For example:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  system('clear')
  print(matrix(rnorm(9), nc = 3))
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want? I ran it on Debian (Ubuntu's mum), and it seemed to do the key tasks.

```
for(ii in 1:10) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    cat(paste0('\r',ii))
}
```

It can also work in batch mode, if that's your thing. I put something similar into in a file, and ran it as `R CMD BATCH --no-save myfile.R`

```
for(ii in 1:10) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    cat(paste0('\r',ii), file='/dev/tty')
}
```

The tricks:

- \r returns you to the beginning of the line. In some environments, you might have to write that as '\\r', but I didn't find that with Debian running R from the console.
- In batch mode, write to /dev/tty, not /dev/console

Hope that helps.