# Print command used to create results in loop

Tags: r, loops, printing

Let's say I have the following loop:

```
test <- mtcars
target_var <- c("mpg", "wt")
group_var <- c("gear", "carb")

library(tidyverse)

for (i in target_var) {
  for (j in group_var) {

print(prop.table(table(test[, i], test[, j]), 2))
  }
}
```

When I run it, I see four prop.tables reported, each with a heading of [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674975/how-do-i-print-a-variable-inside-a-for-loop-to-the-console-in-real-time-as-the)] through [[4]]. I can visually match up which prop.table goes with which variables by looking at the code and seeing the order of variables assigned to target_var and group_var.

But let's say I'm looping through a dozen variables or more. Obviously, it's a problem to match up one particular prop.table (listed as, say, "[[14]]") with the actual variables in that table.

*Is there a way to print the command R used to generate each particular table?*

I am not looking for a [progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674975/how-do-i-print-a-variable-inside-a-for-loop-to-the-console-in-real-time-as-the) but, instead, something that would list the code above each table printed in the console. For example, the following code would be printed right above the appropriate prop.table:

```
prop.table(table(test$mpg, test$gear), 2)
# actual prop.table result from the first time through the loop here

prop.table(table(test$mpg, test$carb), 2)    
# actual prop.table result from the second time through the loop here
```

This would help me when doing exploratory data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want the results of your function to be printed "as you go" (i.e. at each iteration of the loop, not at the end)?

You can use `cat` instead of `print` (be sure to print a new line `\n` after you call `cat` to avoid a messy console):

```
for(i in 1:3) {
    results <- mean(rnorm(10))
    cat(results)
    cat("\n")
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for something different. The results are fine as is, but I'd like the relevant command to be placed above each set of results. So R would print something like:

    `prop.table(table(test$mpg, test$gear), 2)`;

    `# actual prop.table result here`;

    `prop.table(table(test$mpg, test$carb), 2)`;

    `# actual prop.table result here`

Comment: In other words, the console would list the command it just looped through, then the relevant result, and then the next command it looped through, then the relevant result, etc.