# Printing right after user input inside while loop in R

Tags: r, loops, input, while-loop

I am trying to write a code in R that asks an input to the user an indefinite number of times and prints an answer right after reading the input, until the user writes an exit command ("plot" in this case).

The problem is that the code takes the input and gives the correct answer, but the answer is printed only after the while loop ended. Is there a way to get the answer right after every input?

The code I wrote is:

```r
input = readline()
while((toupper(input)!="PLOT")){
  
if(toupper(input)=="W"){cat("white \n")} else if(toupper(input)=="B"){cat("black \n")}
input = readline()    

   }
```

What I get is this (input and then output):

```
W
B 
B
plot
white
white
black
```

What I would like is this:

```
W
white
B
black
B
black
plot
```

Comment: `flush.console()` before the `}` of the loop. Is it better? If so this is a [`duplicate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674975/how-do-i-print-a-variable-inside-a-for-loop-to-the-console-in-real-time-as-the). However your code runs and the question is clear so as a new user you get a +1 from me. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Yes, it works! thanks a lot